# Sprint Boot JPA won't update record with save method

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am rather new to Spring Boot and JPA and am trying to update a record in a mysql database.  In my controller below, I am able to successfully save a new record into the database and lookup existing records. However when I try to update an existing record, nothing happens. (As in, it does not save and skips over the method.)

Here is my controller below. Note, the errorUpdateService.fineErrorByName can successfully retrieve an existing record in Database.

```
@Autowired
private ErrorUpdateService errorUpdateService;


@RequestMapping(value="/api/UpdateError", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String updateError(@RequestBody Error error){
    try{
        Error retrievedError=errorUpdateService.findErrorByName((error.getName()));
        if(!retrievedError.getName().equals("NVE")){
            System.out.println("Here is error: "+retrievedError.toString());
            errorUpdateService.updateError(retrievedError);
            return retrievedError.getName() + " has been updated";
        }
    }catch(NullPointerException e){
        errorUpdateService.updateError(error);
        return "Error Name Does not Exist.  Saving " +error.getName() ;
    }
    return "Failed Method";
}
```

When the code executes to  `errorUpdateService.updateError(retrievedError);` it does not save to the database and appears to skip over.  However, if you send in an record that does NOT exist in the database, it saves no problem (see Null Pointer catch block).

See ErrorUpdateServiceImpl below
'

```
@Autowired
private ErrorRepository errorRepository;

@Override
public void updateError(Error error) {
    System.out.println("Attempting to save a error: "+error.toString());
    errorRepository.save(error);
}

@Override
public Error findErrorByName(String errName){

    try{
        Error error=errorRepository.findByErrName(errName);

        return error;
    }catch(NullPointerException e){
        return new Error("NVE");
    }   
}
```

'

```
public interface ErrorRepository extends JpaRepository<Error, Long>{

    Error findByErrName(String errName);
}
```

Here is an example console output when trying to update a record:

```
Hibernate: select error0_.id as id1_0_, error0_.documentationurl as document2_0_, error0_.err_name as err_name3_0_, error0_.error_id as error_id4_0_, error0_.has_documentation as has_docu5_0_, error0_.last_incident_time as last_inc6_0_, error0_.throttle_minutes as throttle7_0_, error0_.throttle_threshold as throttle8_0_ from error error0_ where error0_.err_name=?
Here is error: Error [id=6, errorId=0, hasDocumentation=false, errName=Error0001, documentationURL=null, throttleThreshold=0, throttleMinutes=0, lastIncidentTime=null]
Attempting to save a error: Error [id=6, errorId=0, hasDocumentation=false, errName=Error0001, documentationURL=null, throttleThreshold=0, throttleMinutes=0, lastIncidentTime=null]
```

Comment: on a side note you shouldn't be  catching the `NullPointerException`s..

Comment: So you're using a `NullPointerException` catching to avoid the null checking over `retrievedError`? Just do it in a condition, man. Regarding to your question, does Hibernate throw any specific exception when you try to update?

Comment: Catch and handle the exception, don't convert them to some special object. Why do you expect `findByErrName` to throw a NullPointerException?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I missing something or you are trying to update a record, with the same record you retrieve? You are updating it with the exact same values, so maybe that's why you don't see any changes?

Comment: Wow you are completely right. I can't believe I missed that. Thanks a lot for taking a look :)

Comment: No problem! Glad it was only that and not an undetectable error.